# Font Awesome is rendering "[object object]" if placed next to a concatenated text

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I have a `Button` component to be used overall the platform, and it has a props `textIcon` which, if filled, is supposed to show a `react-fontawesome` icon beside the `text` prop.

```
class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    const { text, textIcon, loadingText, className, onClick, disabled, isFormGroup } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={cx(isFormGroup && "form-group")}>
        <button className={className} onClick={onClick} disabled={disabled}>
          {
            disabled
              ? loadingText
              : textIcon ? `${<FontAwesomeIcon icon={textIcon}/>} ${text}` : text
          }
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The problem is that the `FontAwesome` component is displaying as `[object object] if it is next to a text, but it shows the icon if it's only it. I've tried the following ways, without success:

```
`${<FontAwesomeIcon icon={textIcon}/>} ${text}`

<FontAwesomeIcon icon={textIcon}/> + ` ${text}`
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try not to concat the text and the icon by wrapping it with another element. If you don't want to have a `<span>` or something in your button, you could use `React.Fragment`:

```js
import { Fragment } from 'react'; // import Fragment from React


<button className={className} onClick={onClick} disabled={disabled}>
        {
          disabled
            ? loadingText
            : textIcon ? 
                <Fragment>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={textIcon}/> 
                    {text}
                </Fragment> 
                : text
        }
</button>
```

> **Info:** Fragments let you group a list of children without adding extra nodes to the DOM. More: https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I did not know about the `Fragment`. But why was it like that?

Comment: Content in back ticks ends up as a string once interpolated. So `\`${<FontAwesomeIcon/>}\`` isn't an object, it's a string. `<FontAwesomeIcon/>` itself is an *object*, so when you try to put it into a string you get a string with the content "[object object]".

Answer (score 1):

In your first solution you are rendering a String here.
React Components/elements are plain JS objects.
If the object is not serializable they get rendered as `[object object]`.

You need to wrap it with

```
<React.Fragment>
 <FontAwesomeIcon icon={textIcon}/> 
  {text}
</React.Fragment>
```

Your second solution doesn't work because
ternary objects should return one thing only.
by doing `<FontAwesomeIcon icon={textIcon}/> +  ${text}` you are actually returning two objects.

- `React.createElement(FontAwesomeIcon)`
- and second the string object `{text}`.